# Rails - how to get ID of record matching other condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Category table and, based on knowing the category name (it is unique), I want to get able to get the ID.

In rails console I tried

```
cat = Category.where("name = ?", "Food")
```

which successfully found the object, but typing cat[:id] gives me "TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find_by_name` instead.

```
cat = Category.find_by_name('Food')
puts cat.id
```

`where` returns an array (well, array-like) object. So, you could instead use `cat = Category.where('name = ?', 'Food').first`. The find methods will do the same thing, but look cleaner too.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat = Category.where("name = ?", "Food").first
id = cat.id
```